# Flask function's POST method is resetting variables received from JavaScript (via POST) as JSON to None on "submit" event. How can I avoid that?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to access JavaScript variables from the POST method of a flask function (using `request.get_json()`) in a flask route, and store their values in local variables in that flask function.

In the JS file, I'm using a function, that uses Ajax and jQuery to send those variables to that endpoint via POST method. It gets called way before the final "submit" event occurs on that template.

The flask function does receive the correct values and stores them in those local variables as expected. On "submit", the flask function also takes a form via POST from the corresponding template during that final POST method triggered by the "submit" event, but the local variables that held the values of JavaScript variables are being reset to "None".

As far as I understand, there are two POST methods being triggered, one by the Ajax request, and the other by the template's final "submit" event in flask. The JavaScript variables are not being received by the flask function during the final "submit" event as `request.content_type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in that final POST method, which is why the local variables in flask are getting the None value. I'm trying to do something like this:

Flask route and function:

```
@app.route("/foo", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def foo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        def getJsVars():
            if request.content_type == 'application/json':
                jsVars = request.get_json()
                return jsVars

        def getX(jsonXY):
            if request.content_type == 'application/json':
                x = jsonXY['valueX']
                return x

        def getY(jsonXY):
            if request.content_type == 'application/json':
                y = jsonXY['valueY']
                return y

        x = getX(getJsVars())
        y = getY(getJsVars())

        a = request.form.get('a')
        b = request.form.get('b')

        # * Code for form validation *

        # First, this prints the correct values once,
        # but prints again after "submit" with x and y having None value:
        print("The values are: " x, " ", y)

        return render_template("index.html")
```

JS code:

```
if (window.location.pathname === "/foo") {
    let xVal, yVal;

    function sendXandY(x, y) {
        const valX = x;
        const valY = y

        $.ajax({
            url: '/foo',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                valueX: valX,
                valueY: valY,
            }),
            success: function() {
                console.log("OK - 200");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
        });
    }

    function processXandY() {
        // x and y get their values here
        xVal = 10;
        yVal = 20;

        // Function call to send x and y to url via POST:
        sendXandY(xVal, yVal);
    }

    document.getElementById("get-xy").addEventListener("click", function ()         
    {
        processXandY();
    });
```

The output I'm getting in my flask terminal is something like this:

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2023 12:30:02] "GET /static/script.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
The values are: 10 20

INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2023 12:30:04] "POST /foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
The values are: None None
```

How can I prevent the local variables `x` and `y` of the flask function from being set to None? I'm new at this and have never tried to establish communication between JavaScript and python/flask before. I've tried to read docs but can't figure out hoe to make this work. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A flask route function is no different from a normal python function and each call is independent of every other call with no shared local variables. As you seem to want to process x, y and the form together why not just add them to the form itself and submit everything at once?

Comment: @EAW In the actual program I'm writing, x and y are actually the latitude and longitude of the location clicked by the user on a leaflet js map. So, both latitude and longitude are recorded to JS variables as soon as the user clicks on the map. I managed to work my way around the problem by using 2 global variables, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to do this without having to use global variables.

Comment: Add two hidden fields to your form, one for x and one for y, and populate these from your function processXsndY instead of doing the ajax call.

Comment: @EAW I had that idea but I realized people can play with the HTML in their browser using dev tools. Can't have it exposed to the users.

Comment: Your ajax call is equally susceptible to manipulation as the form data. No client data can ever be trusted and must be validated on receipt by the server.